# IIS Url rewrite from sub-folder to root

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting

I have .net site running on IIS7 and in subfolder is wordpress installed. Is it possible and how to rewrite url so

```
http://example.com/wordpress/page-name/
```

would be accessible by visiting

```
http://example.com/page-name/
```